# Low Speed on wired NIC

Tags: networking, network-interface

O.S : Fedora 32
Kernel Version : 5.6.14-300.fc32.x86_64

I've had an Onboard NIC I can't get my total ISP speed Provider that is 600MB, some month ago this work for me:

I've made a speed test:

https://www.speedtest.net/

What I obtain : 230 more or less on both up and down....

I call to ISP and sent a tech. and in a Laptop with windows they verified the speed was 600mb

I said uhmmm. my OnBoard NIC is gone so I decide to buy Another One:

TP-LINK TG-3269 Gigabit PCI Network Adapter and Add it to a PCI SLOT

Same Result, I didn't get the result what I looking for:

Here is some terminal Output:

```
lspci

02:06.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)

sudo lspci -v
02:06.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8169/8110 Family PCI Gigabit Ethernet NIC
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 20, NUMA node 0
    I/O ports at de00 [size=256]
    Memory at fdeff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at fdf00000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

sudo mii-tool enp2s6                                         
enp2s6: negotiated 1000baseT-HD flow-control, link ok

sudo mii-tool -v enp2s6
enp2s6: negotiated 1000baseT-HD flow-control, link ok
  product info: vendor 00:07:32, model 17 rev 3
  basic mode:   autonegotiation enabled
  basic status: autonegotiation complete, link ok
  capabilities: 1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD
  advertising:  1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
  link partner: 1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control

ethtool -S enp2s6                                                 
NIC statistics:
     tx_packets: 678698
     rx_packets: 1674292
     tx_errors: 0
     rx_errors: 0
     rx_missed: 1352
     align_errors: 0
     tx_single_collisions: 0
     tx_multi_collisions: 0
     unicast: 1673746
     broadcast: 546
     multicast: 0
     tx_aborted: 0
     tx_underrun: 0

bat /sys/class/net/enp2s6/speed
1   │ 1000

bat /sys/class/net/enp2s6/duplex
1   │ full

ip add show

2: enp2s6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:e3:27:04:42:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.155/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s6
       valid_lft 80510sec preferred_lft 80510sec
    inet6 fe80::a431:45ad:da43:453/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

sudo ethtool enp2s6      
Settings for enp2s6:
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: external
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

I'm out of ideas.....

1. Where is all the rest of bits?
2. Is my machine?
3. What is happening here?

Regards., and Thx in advanced...

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /sys/class/net/enp2s6/duplex
1   │ full
```

According to that you have a full duplex link, then 1000baseT-HD is an issue with what `mii-tool` shows.

```
rx_missed: 1352
```

This seems to explain the issue you're facing, the missed rx packets cause re-transmissions. Maybe your system is slow. You could try to enable rx interrupt coalescing, e.g.

```
ethtool -C enp2s6 rx-usecs 200
```

Comment: I've follow your sugestion but I've got -> Cannot set device coalesce parameters: Invalid argument

Comment: 200 may be too big on an ancient RTL8169, try 100 instead.

Comment: works but doesn't help too much

Comment: OK. In case you added the PCI card to a slot behind a PCIe to PCI bridge: There have been problems caused by buggy ASM1083 chips. It would be worth checking whether you have such a chip on your board. In general I'd recommend to go with a more recent PCIe card (if possible with your board).